# spacemacs opens file in terminal split

Tags: spacemacs, ansi-term, neotree

I'm using neotree and as you know it opens a file in the most recent window split you accessed before switching to neotree (window 0).

Sometimes this last accessed split is the ansi-term window I have below (see chart), in this case spacemacs open a file in the terminal split, which is not what I want.

How do I distinguish the terminal split to neotree so that it chooses a "regular" one?

Possibly, this issue is not specific to spacemacs but to emacs in general.
[image]

Comment: I don't use either Spacemacs or Neotree, but I wanted to point out that you can read about how Emacs chooses windows in the Emacs Lisp manual, try evaluating `(info "(elisp)Choosing Window")`. If I had to guess, your issue is not Spacemacs specific, but it is Neotree specific --that's just a guess.